# Do IDP need. P12 or. Developerprofile ？

Tags: ios

I have a iOS app.
My customers give me an Apple ID(TYPE:IN-HOUSE) for distribution.
I'm not allowed to revoke their existing certificates and they do not provide .p12 and .developerprofile.
How can i release the iOS app?

Comment: You will have to get the p12 key with a password I'm afraid. Ask your client for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you need to the public/private key (P12) and the provisioning profile to release an app.

The public/private key is used to sign the with the provisioning profile, without it you can not sign the app. This is needed for all provisioning profil: Development, Ad-Hoc, AppStore and InHouse.

Comment: I called the apple center, they told me 'its OK' and send me Email with some url...Then i still trying. T_T